# expo always returning me with "-bash: expo: command not found" everytime i go to set up a project, "expo init projectname". how do i resolve this?

Tags: react-native, expo

have downloaded latest version of node.js on mac

terminal says ive downloaded latest version of expo cli

if i try to run my first project in terminal; expo init project name, am always met with the same error. -bash: expo: command not found.

when i check terminal to make sure that expo is installed, i am also met with: -bash: expo: command not found.

i have spent at least 3 days trying to resolve this problem.

any help towards this resolution would be greatly appreciated

Comment: please refrain from using very large titles : )

Answer (score 0):

How have you downloaded the Expo CLI? It may be important to note that if you don't install the package globally, like `npm install -g expo-cli`, it may not be properly executable.

[Additionally, One thing I've found when installing commands is that it can help to restart your terminal. Sometimes after you've installed something new, not everything will be in place, but it might be there when the terminal restarts.]

Comment: thanks for the help, so just to confirm ill run you through exactly what ive done so far. first i downloaded node.js, then from there i installed the npm and downloaded git-osx, after downloading those, i then went into terminal and tried 'npm install -g expo-cli'. terminal said expo packages were installed. i then ran 'expo --version' to check expo was running, this is where i have my issues, regardless of if i do it again and again, it always returns me with the message 'expo --version
-bash: expo: command not found'

Comment: Ahh, I'm sorry - in that case, I'm not sure. But this definitely sounds like more of an "npm global package installation" problem than anything specific to react-native or expo